# Azure pipeline run selenium script

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Selenium automation that I wrote in python to test the workflow of my website.
In my script I set a PATH and a webdriver as follow:

```
PATH = "<path-to->/ChromeWebDriver/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

Goes without saying that this works just fine and without any issue. and I am able to run my script.

Now I wanted to try to integrate this script in a azure DevOps pipeline to automate this script every tot hours.

but I am getting and error (reasonable error) during the pipeline trigger.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH
```

I understand that the PATH I have declared in my code, it won't work as not different, but how can I configure my pipeline to add the chrome driver to a windows vm during the process?

because I have a yaml file that is configured as follow

```
trigger:
  - master

variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.x'
      addToPath: true
  - script: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install selenium

  - task: Pythonscript@0
    inputs:
      scriptSource: 'filePath'
      scriptPath: './test.py'
```

Is there a way how I can set the path? thank you so so much in advance

EDIT:
I did something different. In my repo I added ubuntu chrome driver and pointed my `PATH` to that folder. When I run the pipeline in azure, I get this error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I have to download chrome driver for ubuntu, change my configuration pipeline to run on a ubuntu vm, and create a folder with the chromedriver where my pipeline was. and deploy everything.